# How to stop OpenManage Enterprise from automatically checking firmware compliance?

Tags: dell, dell-openmanage

I created some Firmware/Driver Compliance Baselines and OpenManage automatically runs them periodically. I want to run the compliance checks in a manual way. How can I disable the auto run?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your baselines are rechecking compliance automatically, that's most likely because the catalog that those baselines are associated with is set to check for updates automatically, which will run a compliance check on all linked baselines after the check even if no updates were found for that catalog.

You can prevent this by going to Catalog Management and clicking Edit on that catalog, then changing the Update Catalog setting from "Automatically" to "Manually". This will cause the linked baselines to recheck compliance again when the change is applied, but after that the compliance report will only update when you manually run either a baseline compliance check or a catalog update check.